# What is the hydrodynamical explanation for the 'footprint' of a diving whale?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, surface-tension

When a whale dives it leaves behind a so called 'footprint'. The water seems to be calmer or the surface is at least more smooth an shows less wrinkles.

[image]

[Image source](https://aquarium.ucsd.edu/blog/whale-watching-the-tale-of-a-whales-trail/)

I read some text which were talking about a 'wake of the diving whale' but I wanted to understand it from a fluid dynamic (two-phase) point of view, so I thought asking here might be a good idea.

Comment: See conservation of wave action: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_action_(continuum_mechanics)

Comment: What is the source of the text you read? You should provide a reference for your quote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whale creates a vortex ring with its tail, which moves upwards and creates an oval patch of outward current on the surface: short surface waves can't propagate (well) against the current, and that's why the patch is smoother than the ocean around it.

Source: [The flow induced by a mock whale : origin of flukeprint formation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.3893).